# mysql row constructor syntax

Tags: mysql, row

Sorry for the noob question but i could not find any clue in the documentation.
Both queries below are equivalents:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (column1,column2) = (1,1);
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = 1 AND column2 = 1;
```

So does it means that both queries below are equivalents too right?

```
SELECT (1,2) = (1,2); #returns 1
SELECT 1 = 1 AND 2 = 2; #returns 1
```

Soooo if i use '>' instead of '=' what would happen?

```
SELECT (3,0) > (2,2); # returns 1, whaaaaaat?
SELECT 3 > 2 AND 0 > 2; # returns 0, like expected
```

What happened there? why are they not the same?!?! there are other queries that i tested...

```
SELECT (3,0) > (2,2); # 1
SELECT (0,3) > (2,2); # 0
SELECT (3,4) > (3,2);# 1
SELECT (3,0) > (3,2);# 0
SELECT (3,2,1) > (3,2,0); # 1
SELECT (3,2,0) > (3,2,0); # 0
```

Looks like that mysql treats all his arguments as a one big number!
I searched for ROW CONSTRUCTOR SYNTAX in documentation but i could not find any clue about this!
what am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on [comparison operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) says:

> For row comparisons, `(a, b) > (x, y)` is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>   (a > x) OR ((a = x) AND (b > y))
> ```

So `(3, 0) > (2, 2)` is true because `3 > 2`.

The way this works is analogous to the way rows are sorted when using `ORDER BY col1, col2`. It basically tells you if a row with `col1 = a, col2 = b` would be sorted after `col1 = x, col2 = y`.

Comment: Thanks for replying! But why they do that?!? and What would happen if i use >= or <=?

Comment: What is the purpose of making >,<,>=,<= act different of equality operators?

Comment: If you use `>=` or `<=`, the comparisons in the definition become `>=` or `<=`. And I explained the reason in my answer -- comparing multiple columns is done the same way that ordering by multiple columns is done.

Comment: @Barmar, your answer makes great sense, thank you! I have not used ROW constructors before (I'm not a DBA but dev who uses DBs now/then)... my "ah ha" moment: we are comparing rows here, period. So to compare a row, you go column by column to make the equality, greater than, or less than determination. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ashley Another way to think of it is as lexicographic comparison of the lists. You can find the same thing in Python.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar... That's a great way to explain it... taking OP's puzzlement `SELECT (3,0) > (2,2); # returns 1, whaaaaaat?` ...few would not easily see why `"30">"22"` is True in Python. :)

One learning about row constructor comparisons might find discussion on optimization by avoiding them, or docs outlining `>` results in `(a > x) OR ((a = x) AND (b > y))` none of which is explicit about "lexicographic" comparison. Confusion stems from thinking `=` requires all to be equal so `>` must also require all to be greater when—as you pointed out—it's simply lexicographic row comparison. Tx agn!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html) for row constructors, you can see that greater than signs are not handled the same way the equals signs are:

```
(c2,c3) > (1,1)
c2 > 1 OR ((c2 = 1) AND (c3 > 1))
```

Thus, `(3,0) > (2,2)`

Is not:

```
3 > 2 AND 0 > 2;
```

But rather:

```
3 > 2 OR ((3 = 2) AND (0 > 2));
```

You get a return of true, as you only need **either** part of the expression to hold true in an `OR` statement, and the first part of the expression (`3 > 2`) holds true. Thus, you get the expected value return of 1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Omg! your right! Sorry about that! But why they do that?!? and What would happen if i use >= or <=?

Comment: I would **assume** that if you used `(3,0) >= (2,2)` it would follow the structure of `3 >= 2 OR ((3 >= 2) AND (0 >= 2));`, though cannot confirm that.

Comment: Oh okay, i think i got it!

        (c2,c3) >= (1,1) is c2 > 1 OR ((c2 = 1) AND (c3 >= 1))